# Reassigning Instance Variables in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a series of tests I need to run sequentially, and as such, I need to keep common state across all specs. Based on my reading of [before context hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks), I assumed I'd be able to reassign an instance variable from inside an example.

It doesn't seem like I can reassign them, but I can modify them. Here's a working example:

```
require "rspec/expectations"

RSpec.describe "Array", order: :defined do
  before(:context) do
    @array = []
  end

  describe "initialized in before(:context)" do
    it "is empty" do
      expect(@array.size).to eq(0) # Passes
    end

    it "accepts objects" do
      @array << Object.new # Passes
    end

    it "shares state across examples" do
      expect(@array.size).to eq(1) # Passes
    end

    it "can reassign the array" do
      @array = [] # Passes, but this seems to only be assigned locally?
    end

    it "still shares state across examples" do
      expect(@array.count).to eq(0) # => FAILURE: @array.count == 1
    end
  end
end
```

***How can I reassign @array in the above example?***

So just to be clear, I already have a workaround which does not involve reassigning the instance variable. That's posted below. ***I'm not looking for workarounds. I want to understand whether I can reassign the instance variable at all or why I cannot.***

```
# This passes with no issues

RSpec.describe "Array in a Struct", order: :defined do
  before(:context) do
    @o = OpenStruct.new
    @o.array = []
  end

  describe "initialized in before(:context)" do
    it "is empty" do
      expect(@o.array.size).to eq(0) # Passes
    end

    it "accepts objects" do
      @o.array << Object.new # Passes
    end

    it "shares state across examples" do
      expect(@o.array.size).to eq(1) # Passes
    end

    it "can reassign the array" do
      @o.array = [] # Passes
    end

    it "still shares state across examples" do
      expect(@o.array.count).to eq(0) # Passes
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you explicitly running the tests in order?

Comment: Yes. I have even set "order: :defined" in the example I gave.

Comment: Derp; somehow didn't see that when first looked.

Comment: The obvious question here is "But why?"

Comment: Why: expensive setup.

Comment: Do the separate examples actually share the `self` they are executed in? If not this approach won't work I don't thnk.

Comment: Remember: every example works *except for the last one.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect a plain instance variable assignment like that to work, but you can try using `Thread.current` as the storage space.